# Powershell Exchange mailbox report

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to generate a mailbox report for our hosted Exchange platform and automate things a bit. Basically each tenant is in an OU. So I'm trying to first pull a list of OU's, then count the mailboxes in each OU. Here's what I have so far:

```
$ous = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase "OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=yomamma,DC=com" -Filter { (ObjectClass -eq 'organizationalunit') -and (Name -notlike 'Hosted Organization Security Groups') -and (Name -Notlike 'Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations') })

foreach ($ou in $ous) {
(Get-Mailbox -Organization $ou.Name -Filter {( Name -notlike 'Administrator' -and Name -notlike 'DiscoverySearch*' )} -ResultSize unlimited).count
}
```

It works... sort of. The result will be a ton of numbers on each line, a mailbox count for each OU. Problem is, then I have OU's in the $ous variable, and I'm outputting the count to the screen. What I need is output two columns, the OU, alongside the count in another column, so I can pipe it into Export-CSV cmdlet so I can have client name (OU), and the count in a CSV file to them email.

I'm just not sure how to get that combination of data all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to organise information is to put it into an object, if you need to alter the data later on it's already in an object that you can manipulate.

```
$ous = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase "OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=yomamma,DC=com" -Filter { (ObjectClass -eq 'organizationalunit') -and (Name -notlike 'Hosted Organization Security Groups') -and (Name -Notlike 'Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations') })

foreach ($ou in $ous)
{
    # This is how many mailboxes this OU has
    $mailboxCount = (Get-Mailbox -Organization $ou.Name -Filter {( Name -notlike 'Administrator' -and Name -notlike 'DiscoverySearch*' )} -ResultSize unlimited).count

    # This is a fancy object to store our information
    $mailboxObject = New-Object psobject -Property ([Ordered]`
    @{
        "OU" = $ou
        "MailboxCount" = $mailboxCount
    })

    # You can export your CSV here or do other stuff
    # $mailboxObject | Export-CSV C:\MyPath -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Small note:  If you're not using PowerShell v3 take out the `[Ordered]` attribute :)

Comment: That seems to be a better way to do it... I wasn't familiar with New-Object. However can't get it to run. I'm getting a "The Type initializer for 'Microsoft.Exchange.Diagnostics.ETraceConfiguration' threw an exception. Category Info: OperationStaopped, PSRemotingTransportException, FullyQualifiedErrorId: JobFailure"

I did think maybe I needed to modify the line with ""OU" = $ou" to ""OU = $ou.Name" perhaps, since the $ou variable will contain a lot more information, and I just need the Name value. Still get the same result. I am running powershell 3.

Comment: Ok, not sure why but my Powershell window kept crashing using PowerShell 3. However I can run the script fine on a different server with Powershell 2 on it. One issue was the foreach loop above would overwrite $mailboxObject each time it ran, so ultimately the CSV would end up with a single line in it. So I added a "$mailboxList = @()" array, then after your New-Object ran "$mailboxList += $mailboxCount" then did Export-CSV on the $mailboxList array. This got the output needed.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the answer is very simple. This will output csv content. If you'd prefer, you can drop the quotes and replace the comma with a `t, then you can copy/paste from the PowerShell console into Excel.

```
$ous = (Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase "OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=yomamma,DC=com" -Filter { (ObjectClass -eq 'organizationalunit') -and (Name -notlike 'Hosted Organization Security Groups') -and (Name -Notlike 'Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations') })

foreach ($ou in $ous) {
    '"' + $ou.Name + '",' + (Get-Mailbox -Organization $ou.Name -Filter {( Name -notlike 'Administrator' -and Name -notlike 'DiscoverySearch*' )} -ResultSize unlimited).count
}
```